# Rails' session does not persist on Chrome 67 and below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 routes, one sets the session variable and one that reads it.

But on Chrome 67 and below, the session variable doesn't persist.

Here is a one file Rails app that reproduces the issue.

```rb
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile(true) do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'
end

require 'rails'
require 'action_controller/railtie'

class TestApp < Rails::Application
  config.eager_load = 'development'
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.secret_key_base = '669846b267cea64315663e4f5c124096'
  config.secret_token = '9c9846b2f7cea64315503e4f5c124094'

  routes.append do
    get '/' => 'api#index'
    post '/api/set' => 'api#set' # SET THE SESSION
    get '/api/get' => 'api#get' # READ THE SESSION
  end
end

class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  HTML_STRING = <<-EOF
    <script>
      fetch('/api/set', { method: 'POST' }) // SET THE SESSION
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((r) => {
          console.log('SET: ', r);

          fetch('/api/get')
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((r) => console.log('GET: ', r)); // READ THE SESSION
        });
    </script>
  EOF

  def index
    render :html => HTML_STRING.html_safe
  end

  def set 
    session[:x] = 'x'

    render :json => { :x => session[:x] }
  end

  def get
    render :json => { :x => session[:x] }
  end
end

TestApp.initialize!

run TestApp
```

Save the file as `config.ru` and to run use `rackup -p 3030`.

Output on Chrome 68 and above:

```js
SET:  {x: 'x'}
GET:  {x: 'x'}
```

Output on Chrome 67 and below:

```js
SET:  {x: 'x'}
GET:  {x: null}
```

Live Reproduction: https://hidden-mesa-94224.herokuapp.com/

I tested on almost all versions by using [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) and found that the issue only persists on Chrome below 67.

Chrome 67 Network Tab:
[image: Network Tab]

Chrome 95 Network Tab:
[image]

Comment: Please update with the Network Waterfall. Are those requests triggered in the correct order in Chrome < 67 ? That's the only thing that comes to mind .. I'm seeing the js code which triggers the requests, maybe it's a bug in fetch API ?

Comment: @razvans Added network waterfall.

Comment: @razvans Just like you said, I think it might be a bug on fetch API, I replaced `fetch` with `axios` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Aah very good because I had no other ideas :D